# Android, How to programatically add cancel and ok button to custom dialog?

Tags: android, xml

I have custom dialog created by using this code:

```
public void showEditTextModalWindow(View view) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PodShipmentDetail.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Edit shipment note");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_custom);

    dialog.show();
    Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "SHOW DIALOG");
}
```

I would like to ask, how can i add programatically OK and Cancel button with onClick listener..

Something like this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// Do nothing but close the dialog
   dialog.dismiss();
}
});
```

I don't want to add button in XML because i would like to have buttons in design typical for alert dialog in Android(Not gray, not ugly)..

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can have the buttons in xml and also customize the same the way you want applying styles to the same.

Comment: what's the need to use `Dialog` instead of `AlertDialog`?

Comment: If you look at the source for the original Android Dialog's they have the buttons in XML , it is not programmatic or VooDoo

Answer (score 1):

[image: custom dialog]

**alert_dialog.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="HardcodedText,ContentDescription" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8aaf9b">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_left" android:layout_width="160dp" android:text="OK"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="@drawable/button_left" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_right" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/button_right" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Title" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvMessage" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/btn_left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle" android:text="Message" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AlertDialog.java**:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class AlertDialog extends Dialog {
    private Button alertOk, alertCancel;
    private TextView tvTitle, tvMessage;
    View v = null;

    public AlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        v = getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        alertOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_left);
        alertCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_right);
        alertOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        tvTitle.setText(title);
    }

    public void setMessage(CharSequence msg) {
        tvMessage.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

**left_normal.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#919191"/>
</shape>
```

**left_pressed.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#5e5e5e"/>
</shape>
```

**right_normal.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#919191"/>
</shape>
```

**right_pressed.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#5e5e5e"/>
</shape>
```

**button_left.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/left_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/left_normal" />
</selector>
```

**button_right.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/right_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/right_normal" />
</selector>
```

**How to show dialog**:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(context);
alertDialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
alertDialog.setMessage("Custom Dialog!!\n\n\n(Facebook.com/Awais.is.King)");
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

add button for ok or cancel and add this code:

```
Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      dialog.dismiss();
   }
});
```

so this should look like this:

```
public void showEditTextModalWindow(View view) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PodShipmentDetail.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Edit shipment note");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_custom);

    Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          dialog.dismiss();
       }
    });

    dialog.show();
    Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "SHOW DIALOG");
}
```

Comment: But if i create button in XML i must style him. Exist any predefined style or something else, how to avoid the button stylling?

Comment: Just add it, no need to style it.

Comment: In official Android docs buttons for custom layout are not defined in layout too. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: do you want whole custom dialog?

Comment: Yes i want custom dialog using the template.

Comment: I'm adding the whole custom dialog code in new answer.